# Testing an Array of String in for loop java

Tags: java, swing

I just learned the basics of Java and I am trying to make a simple Login program that tests a user and password from a String Array, but when the events trigger nothing happens button is just stuck.

```
private void btn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    //List of user and pass as an array
    final String[] userlist = {"admin","test","lol","user"};
    final String[] passlist = {"123","test","lol","user"};

    //testing if correct
    for(int i = 0; i > 5;i++){
    if (userbox.getText().equals(userlist[i]) & passbox.getText().equals(passlist[i])){
      //pops up a new panel if success
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Success");
      new InputOutput().setVisible(true);
      this.hide();
    }else{
      //pops up a message if its wrong
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Wrong Try again!");
    }
}
```

Comment: At a guess `for(int i = 0; i > 5;i++){` should probably be `for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++){` or. better `for(int i = 0; I < userlist.length;i++){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the condition in your for loop, which is `i > 5`, is incorrect, because it will never be met since `i` starts from `0`. Also it is probably better to use the actual length of your username array, which is `userlist.length`, for the condition, because it might changy when you edit your code.

Secondly, in the if statement where you check whether the input is correct or not, you use a bitwise AND `&` instead of a logical AND `&&`, which is probably by accident, because the goal is to check if both the username and the password are correct.

Here is a version of this part of your code, where I have edited out the mistakes:

```
for(int i = 0; i < userlist.length; i++) {
if(userbox.getText().equals(userlist[i]) && passbox.getText().equals(passlist[i])) {
    // Success
} else {
    // Failure
}
```